# Duplicate a collection of entities and persist in Hibernate/JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, collections, jpa

I want to duplicate a collection of entities in my database.
I retreive the collection with:

```
CategoryHistory chNew = new CategoryHistory();
CategoryHistory chLast =  (CategoryHistory)em.createQuery("SELECT ch from CategoryHistory ch WHERE ch.date = MAX(date)").getSingleResult;
List<Category> categories = chLast.getCategories();
chNew.addCategories(categories)// Should be a copy of the categories: OneToMany
```

Now i want to duplicate a list of 'categories' and persist it with EntityManager.
I'm using JPA/Hibernate.
**UPDATE**

After knowing how to detach my entities, i need to know what to detach:
current code:

```
    CategoryHistory chLast =  (CategoryHistory)em.createQuery("SELECT ch from CategoryHistory ch WHERE ch.date=(SELECT MAX(date) from CategoryHistory)").getSingleResult();
    Set<Category> categories =chLast.getCategories();

    //detach
    org.hibernate.Session session = ((org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl) em.getDelegate()).getSession();
    session.evict(chLast);//detaches also its child-entities?       

    //set the realations
    chNew.setCategories(categories);
    for (Category category : categories) {
        category.setCategoryHistory(chNew);
    }
    //set now create date
    chNew.setDate(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

    //persist
    em.persist(chNew);
```

This throws a `failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: entities.CategoryHistory.categories, no session or session was closed` exception.

I think he wants to lazy load the categories again, as i have them detached. What should i do now?

Comment: in that case, what do you mean by "copy"? And why doesn't this work for you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aaron Diguila's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973877/duplicate-a-collection-of-entities-and-persist-in-hibernate-jpa/1973982#1973982) is the way to go here, i.e. you need to `detach` your instances, set the business key to `null` and then `persist` them.

Sadly, there is no way to disconnect one object from the entity manager with JPA 1.x (JPA 2.0 will have `EntityManager.detach(Object)` and fix this). So, either wait for JPA 2.x (not an option I guess) or use Hibernate's underlying `Session`.

To do so, you can cast the delegate of an EntityManager to an Hibernate Session.

```
Session session = (Session) em.getDelegate();
```

Of course, this only works if you use Hibernate as a Java Persistence provider, because the delegate is the Session API.

Then, to detach your object:

```
session.evict(object);
```

**UPDATE:** According to [Be careful while using EntityManager.getDelegate()](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/2009/05/25/be-careful-while-using-entitymanagergetdelegate), with GlassFish one should actually use (and likely in your case too) :

```
org.hibernate.Session session = ((org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl) em.getDelegate()).getSession();
```

But this would **not** work in JBoss that [suggest](http://bill.burkecentral.com/2007/07/06/co-existence-with-hibernate-jpa-and-ejb3/) to use the code previously mentioned.

```
org.hibernate.Session session = (Session) em.getDelegate();
```

While I understand that using `getDelegate()` makes JPA code non-portable, I must admit that I was not expecting the result of this method call to be implementation specific.

**UPDATE2:** To answer the updated part of the question, I'm not sure that you eagerly loaded the categories. This is not the best way to do this but what happens if you call `categories.get(0)` before eviction? Also, I may be missing that part but, where do you nullify the key of categories?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but it was already very clear what Aaron said:)

Comment: @Michael Indeed but 1. Aaron didn't mention initially how to get the `Session` 2. while answering, you are not notified by comments to answers so I didn't notice he answered that part 3. I wanted to mention that JPA 2.0 does have the `detach()` method and Aaron didn't mention that. And at the end, it looks like you are going this way so at least one guy found it valuable.

Answer (score 8):

You need to detach your instances from the session. There are three ways to do this:

1. Close the session (probably not possible in your case).
2. Serialize the object and deserialize it again.
3. Clone the object and clear/null the primary key/id field.

Then you must change the business key (so the new instances will return `false` when calling `equals()` with an unmodified instance). This is the important step: Without it, Hibernate will reattach the instances to the existing ones in the DB or you'll get other, strange errors.

After that, you can save the new copies just like any other instance.

Comment: Thank you, I understand your answer.
Is it possible to detach from the Entitymanager? If not how can i get the current hibernate session? Thank you!!

Comment: `(Session)em.getDelegate ()` gets you the current session. The EM has no method to detach objects, you can only remove (= delete) them.

Comment: @Aaron: Would it work with other JPA implementations? Just curious, because the method return a generic Object type instance and they said its implementation specific.

Comment: I can't find the detach method on a org.hibernate.Session? Or am i blind?https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/api/org/hibernate/Session.html

Comment: Even, Session s = ((Session)em.getDelegate()); throws: ClassCastException: org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl cannot be cast to org.hibernate.Session

Comment: Argh ... yeah, no detach(). You must clone the object and make sure the primary key (the ID) is cleared/nulled.

Comment: As for the classcast, you'll need to examine the returned object in a debugger. The delegate depends on your JPA framework and how you setup JPA. So it's a bit different for each of them (JBoss, Hibernate, Spring, ...)

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

Since I'm using glassfish v3, and JPA2.0 is final, i used the EntityManager.detach()
Strangely ejb3-persistence.jar was included in my lib, so i throwed it out and used javax.persistence of the glassfish jar. The detach method is there but my hibernate version has no implementation yet

Comment: So actually, there was some value in mentioning that this method was there in JPA 2.0.

Comment: @Michael: Please don't post comments to your question as answers. Edit the question instead.

Comment: @Aaron, ok I thought this could be an answer for other using a implementation of JPA 2.0 :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Clone or copy properties of each object. You can use Apache `BeanUtils.copyProperties(copy, orig)`
2. In OpenJPA, manually remove monitoring of entity using Apache BeanUtils:

   `BeanUtils.setProperty(copy, "pcVersionInit", false);`
3. Set the primary key to default/null.
4. Persist each copy.

Also see: http://www.java-tutorial.ch/java-persistence-api/how-to-persist-duplicate-of-an-entity-with-openjpa