# Add new Instances to tables using JPA

Tags: java, database, jpa, eclipselink, derby

I using the following code and when I read the entry from the tables (derby db - eclipse link)
there is just one entry ,how should I add new entries? for example to add same entry 5 times ?

```
for (Object object : listClsObj) {
    int cnt = 1;
    do {
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.persist(object);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        cnt++;
    }
    while (cnt < 6);
        }
em.close();
```

The entity class is :

```
@Entity
public class Person {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
private String id;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;

public String getId() {

    return id;
}

public void setId(String Id) {

    this.id = Id;
}

public String getFirstName() {

    return firstName;
}
```

When I put breakpoint at em persist and in the second loop change the id value  I got the following error :

> Exception Description: The attribute [id] of class [DerbyModel.Person]
>   is mapped to a primary key column in the database. Updates are not
>   allowed. Exception in thread "main"
>   javax.persistence.RollbackException: Exception [EclipseLink-7251]
>   (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.1.v20121003-ad44345):
>   org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException Exception
>   Description: The attribute [id] of class [DerbyModel.Person] is mapped
>   to a primary key column in the database. Updates are not allowed.

Comment: What entity are you persisting? Show us the entity class. And where did you populate your `listClsObj`?

Comment: You are persisting the same object over and over again (5 times) - is this really what you want?

Comment: yes I need to build there dummy data

Comment: Does your listClsObj contain 5 objects with the same firstName and lastName?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When calling `em.persist(object)`, the instance refered by `object` is probably assigned an `id` by the dbms, and remains attached to the jpa session. This means that the instance `object` refers to is already persisted, and subsequent calls to `persist` will do nothing besides from trying to persist it again (same id, same values).

You'd probably need to create new instances of `Person` at every execution of the loop, and persist each one of them, or try to detach the instance (by means of [`em.detach()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#detach%28java.lang.Object%29), for instance) and reset its id.

Untested sample:

```
for (Object object : listClsObj) {
    int cnt = 1;
    do {
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.persist(object);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.detach(object);
        ((Person)object).setId(null);
        cnt++;
    }
    while (cnt < 6);
        }
em.close();
```

Comment: I have try to change the id value and got error any idea how to overcome this? I update my question with this details

Comment: Have you tried detaching objects from the session before trying to reset the key (`em.detach(object)`)? You can also find useful answers in this question: [Duplicate a collection of entities and persist in Hibernate/JPA](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1973877/851811)

Comment: Try [`em.detach()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#detach(java.lang.Object)).

Comment: Thanks man ,one last question here we cast hardcoded (Person) can I do that from the object (assume that i dont know the class name just during RT

Comment: You could either make your persisted classes implement an interface providing a getter/setter for id, or try to find the method by means of reflection.